How to Group Products by Category in a HubSpot Quote?
I have a product object in HubSpot with a custom field called "Product Category" which can have values like:
Category A
Category B
Category C
When generating a quote, I would like to group all products by their category. Ideally, the quote should be structured so that products under each category are grouped together, with subtotals for each category and a grand total at the end.
For example, the quote should look something like shown in the image.(https://i.sstatic.net/EDm5wKlZ.png)
So Is there a way to achieve this grouping in HubSpot, either through customization or custom code or by using any existing features?
I explored the HubSpot quote templates to see if there was an option to group products by category, but I couldn't find a built-in feature to do so. I also tried creating custom line items and sections manually within the quote editor, but this approach doesn’t automate the process, making it impractical for larger quotes. I checked the available customization options, but I’m not sure how to proceed with grouping items by the "Product Category" custom field in a way that reflects the structure I need.
